# Powershell and logparser arguments

Tags: powershell, arguments, logparser

Im trying to run some logparser commands from powershell but Im having issues with passing the arguments across correctly, heres the excert from my script;

d:\scripting\smtplogs\logparser\logparser.exe "SELECT TOP 50 Receiver, COUNT(*) INTO %TMPOutput%\TopReceiversNDRALL.gif FROM %TempDir%\PostAll.log WHERE Sender LIKE '<>' AND Receiver NOT LIKE '%%go-fmtopper%%' GROUP BY Receiver ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC"  -i:TSV  -iSeparator:space  -headerRow:OFF -iHeaderFile:"header3.tsv" -lineFilter:"+10." -o:CHART -chartType:ColumnClustered -config:MyScript.js -chartTitle:"Receivers for NULL messages ALL for %DateGraph%"

Ive read loads about encapsulating arguments but cant seem to figure out how to make this work!

Any help that you guys could provide would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: +1 - Not sure why this got voted down, seems like a fine question to me...  Fellow Andy looking out for other Andys

Comment: Yeah it puzzled me, I know its abit of a noob question but its annoying the life out of me!

Comment: +1 Yeah, I consider this a valid question since it's sometimes quite perplexing how to pass a string with a lot of single/double quotes in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a complex string parameter, try to pass the argument using powershell [here-strings](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/pstips/jun07/pstip0629.mspx) so that you wouldn't have to worry about escaping single/double quotes

***UPDATE1***: I couldn't get the fomratting working so here is the screenshot.
[image]

***UPDATE2***: I was able to format the code finally.

```
d:\scripting\smtplogs\logparser\logparser.exe @"
SELECT TOP 50 Receiver, COUNT() 
INTO %TMPOutput%\TopReceiversNDRALL.gif 
FROM %TempDir%\PostAll.log 
WHERE Sender LIKE '' 
      AND Receiver NOT LIKE '%%go-fmtopper%%' 
GROUP BY Receiver 
ORDER BY COUNT() DESC" 
-i:TSV 
-iSeparator:space 
-headerRow:OFF 
-iHeaderFile:"header3.tsv" 
-lineFilter:"+10." 
-o:CHART 
-chartType:ColumnClustered 
-config:MyScript.js 
-chartTitle:"Receivers for NULL messages ALL for %DateGraph%
"@
```

Make sure that you add a new line between the here-string monikers **@"** and **"@**.

Comment: As always mate, you'ce cracked it, I hadnt even heard of here-strings! Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, glad to hear that I was able to spread the power of hear-strings. It is great to spread powershell's functionalities ;)

Answer (score 1):

FYI, if you don't need any PowerShell variable expansion then you are better off using single quoted here strings.  For example the following double quoted here string might cause you some grief:

```
@"
$(get-process <some_core_os_process> | stop-process)
"@
```

where the following is harmless:

```
@'
$(get-process <some_core_os_process> | stop-process)
'@
```

It's not likely your here string would contain something so obvious but a simple $f would resolve to nothing i.e. it would disappear from the original string.  Unless, of course, $f was defined and set to something other than null or empty.